# How do I compile PortAudio on Windows in Visual Studio Community 2015?

Tags: c++, portaudio

If I attempt to build PortAudio using the `.sln` file included in the latest download, I get these errors.

[image: Cannot include ... ASIO]

What is interesting however is that I have set the preprocessor flag `PA_USE_ASIO` to 0, as shown here.

[image: PA_USE_ASIO=0]

If I delete the ASIO directory (/src/hostapi/asio), I no longer get errors related to the ASIO files but instead receive an error related to `ksguid.lib`.

[image: TargetName does not match linker OutputFile, cannot open ksguid.lib]

Googling around says that the `PA_WDMKS_NO_KSGUID_LIB` preprocessor flag should stop this ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/extemporelang/mJRnrBAdo0A)) but it doesn't seem to work. As if it's ignoring the preprocessor flags entirely.

Alternatively, if there is a better library which works similarly to PortAudio, I'd be happy to hear about it (I'm trying to do some real time DSP).

Answer (score 1):

First Problem, Linker Problem:

You can change the Output FileName on 
`Project -> Properties -> Linker -> General`
 (1. Point on Linker, I dont use the English Version of VS)
Change the outputname in the first column from `portaudio_x86` to `portaudio`

Second Problem:

You need to define the full Pathname of the `ksguid.lib file.` The file should be probably here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64\ksguid.lib`. Or for x86 Application in the folder above. Paste the link here: `Project > Properties > Configuration-Properties > Linker > Input -> Additional Dependencies`

I got the same Problem as you, after i've done this, it builds the Project succesfully, but if i want to execute it in Visual Studio it gives me an error - 
`the portaudio.dll could not be opened, Unknown error 0x800700c1.`
 Do you or anyone have a reason for this?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot run a .dll file even in visual studio as it is a library to support other applications that you would build PortAudio specifically streams audio it can be utilized either by placing the .dll file in the projects folder for the system main folder.

Comment: From the question: "If I attempt to **build** PortAudio". Was not trying to run the DLL when I asked this question over 2 years ago :o